# Liferay Bean locator error

Tags: liferay, portlet

I am developing liferay portlet.

When I create the service.xml file and build it, and then execute my portlet I get a bean locator error.

I have checked that all things are right.

Comment: Are there more error details? How does the content of the service.xml file look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you better write whole error, but this may because of uppercase or lowercase mistake in service.xml file and your field names.
I have encountered with this error once because of a field with the name of ISBN and I change its first letter with lowercase and that's it. :D
Check that once again and return with your feedback. :)

Comment: thanks alot. i change field name and this is resolved.my field start with upper case.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your service is not build properly.Try re-building the service.xml file.